# Parse xml file with a nested structure with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I have an xml-file with the following structure:

```
<field>
    <title>Wrong</title>
    <value>Don't want this</value>
</field>
<field>
    <title>Dialogue Text</title>
    <value>The gold is here</value>
</field>
```

How can I use jQuery to get the text inside the value-tag, but only if the text inside the title-tag above it was "Dialogue Text"?

In other words, how can I select the value based on the content of the title tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you are doing is looking for a collection of the valid ones you can do something like:

```js
var validValues=$(xml).find('title').filter( function(){
    return $(this).text() === 'Dialogue Text';
}).siblings('value');

/* now do something with the collection of value tags */
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fyemcku1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Looks good but I have one question: how can I get the actual text? I tried to write into the html simply "validValues" instead of "validValues.length" in your Fiddle, but that resulted in [object, object]. How can I access the sentence?

Comment: depends if there will be more than one or not... if only one then using `text()` will work, if more than one you would need to loop over the collection

Comment: Great, thank you. I'm selecting this as the answer because the code is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more elegant way to do this, but this will work:

```
var x = $.parseXML("<n>" + xmlString + "</n>");

var text = $(x).find("field")
               .filter(function() { 
                    return $(this).children("title").text() ===
                         "Dialogue Text"
               })
               .children("value")
               .text();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zcm1778w/

If the check for "Dialogue Text" can be a "contains" match instead of an exact match, you can make this a bit tidier:

```
var x = $.parseXML("<n>" + xmlString + "</n>");

var selector = "field:has(title:contains('Dialogue Text')) value";
var text = $(x).find(selector).text();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zcm1778w/2/